# IBM/Google PhD Fellowship along with current salary

Tags: phd, funding, germany

In Germany, PhD are covered by salary as a research assistant. But, is it possible to apply for an extra scholarship like IBM/Google PhD Fellowship?

If selected, is it legal to take both fellowship and the Salary?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is explicitly spelled out both in the fellowship contract and your university contract. Besides legal and moral implications, most organizations have zero incentive to give double full-time salary for the same job.

Comment: I am also in such a kind of job and I was not eligible.

Comment: With a public contract in Germany, you are entitled to a "Nebentätigkeit" (side job) up to X  hours (typically X = around 8h/week).  For a fellowship, the situation might be different. But you will need to check both your fellowship conditions and the with the university (Does your fellowship come with obligations? Could these obligations conflict with your university contract?)

Comment: @user151413 Okay, thank you. But if somebody works for more than 8 hours, how does the employer check it?

Comment: @Coder Did you check with scholarship committee or university?

Comment: @AlexKujur If you break the law, how will anyone find out? You don't know, and you probably have a good change of getting away with it, just like with cheating on your taxes or jaywalking.  But don't complain if you are caught and fired.  
Point is: Even if it is <8h, you need to inform your employer (or, depending on the type of job, get a permission).  So either you are honest here, or you lie about the hours.  Lying is generally not a good idea, at least if you get caught.